# Does anyone know how to change the Properties.Settings.Default.{} form App.xaml.cs?

Tags: wpf, xml, app.xaml

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I need some way to change Properties.Settings.Default when my application starts by adding values from am xml if it exists and bypass the StartupUri from App.xaml, actually creating a different window. If that xml file doesn't exist Run the StartupUri from the App.xaml (which will be a login Window).

Any ideas?

Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the startupuri from your app.xaml an override OnStartup() in your app.xaml.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    //todo settings
    var login = new LoginWindow();
    var result = login.ShowDialog()

    //do something with result

    this.MainWindow = new MyMainWindow();
    this.MainWindow.Show();
}
```

i dont know what you really want with your Properties.Settings...

Comment: I need to implement some sort of  remember password functionality to my App and I use Properties.Settings to be some kind of $_SESSION variable. Thanks

Comment: **can anyone suggest how to do this more efficient ?** thank you

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still looking.. Lookup the property values in Properties.Settings.Default from the OnStartup method in app.xaml.cs, use the property to determine if the user wants a login:

App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        bool b = YourNamespace.Properties.Settings.Default.SettingUseLogin;

        if (b)
            this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("LoginWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);
        else
            this.StartupUri = new System.Uri("MainWindow.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative);

    }
}
```